# Changing value of NSNumber in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I've been trying to figure out how to change the value of an NSNumber I have stored in an NSMutableDictionary. I had to use an NSNumber because only objects can be stored in an NSDictionary. This is what I have right now and it isn't acting as I expected.

```
    int newInt = [self.myDict[@"key"] intValue] + 100;
    NSLog(@"%d",newInt);
    [self.myDict setObject:@(newInt) forKey:@"key"];
    NSLog(@"%d",[self.myDict[@"key"] intValue]);
```

The first NSLog prints 100 as I expected but the second prints 0. How should I be changing the value of the NSNumber in that dictionary? Thanks for the help!

Comment: is `self.myDict` initialised?

Comment: That should work. Have you logged self.myDict to make sure it's not nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that self.myDict is nil. Log it and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

You need: self.myDict = [NSMutableDictionary new]; prior to setting values in it.

Example:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *myDict;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.myDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    int newInt = [self.myDict[@"key"] intValue] + 100;
    NSLog(@"%d",newInt);
    [self.myDict setObject:@(newInt) forKey:@"key"];
    NSLog(@"%d",[self.myDict[@"key"] intValue]);
}
```